# Date time format conversion in R

Tags: r

I read couple questions/answers here, but I can't seem to fix a date time problem.

How do I convert the dates `6/18/14 10:55 AM` to `2014-06-18` (yyyy-mm-dd)? So, I just have dates at the end not time.

Below is what I have done:

```
data <- data.frame(date = c( "6/18/14 10:55 AM", "10/8/14 3:10 PM",  "10/31/14     12:24 PM","6/18/14 10:55 AM", "12/2/14 12:52 PM", "11/24/14 12:31 PM"))
str(data) #variable is factor 

data$date <- as.POSIXct(data$date)

data #Preview
```

(Also I am not able to add the above code in code format for stackoverflow. Sorry for inconvenience).

Comment: you should read `?strptime` `as.Date(as.character(data$date), '%m/%d/%y')`

Comment: Try `as.Date(data$date, "%m/%d/%y")`  (Note that `as.Date` has a `"factor"` method so there is no need to convert it to `"character"` class first.)

Comment: Thanks! Both your codes helped. Just for my knowledge, if wanted to convert the time along with date, which code name should I be using? For example: would this as.POSIXct work?

Comment: Actually, the code slight didn't work. It changing from 6/18/14 10:55 AM to 2020-06-18. Year is 2014 is converted to 2020. Any idea?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Please see above.

Answer (score -1):

With the help from above users, figured the problem. as.Date(data$date, "%m/%d/%Y") works. %Y should be capital.

Comment: No it should not be %Y.  It should be %y if the data is as shown in the question.

Comment: Really strange. %y and %Y works with this data. However, when I tried to run on another data set, %y gives me the year 2020 instead of 2014. But %Y fixes the problem. What is the difference between %y and %Y?